# JNI and abstract classes

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, abstract-methods

I have two questions regarding the Java Native Interface and Abstract Classes

1. Is it possible for the JNI to invoke an abstract Java method from within C++, essentially using JNI to create abstract classes that have to be extended in Java?
2. Is it possible to override Native JNI methods with Java methods?

That is all.

Comment: It's not clear where you are coming from. My reaction is 1. Define abstract classes in Java. 2. Inheritance gives you the opportunity for overrides. So, neither relates to JNI.

Comment: By abstract class, I mean a class with abstract methods - a class that exists to be inherited from, to be subclassed.

Comment: Creating a class at runtime would be no different in JNI than in Java (but it's very rarely done, even in Java). I can't think of a way to use such a class without creating subclasses at runtime, too.